# Multiple jquery Datepicker with start end validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, datepicker

Hi I would appreciate any assistance with regards to my problem

I am able to make the jQuery Datepicker work with the start/end date validation if I only have 1 datepicker for both start and end.

However, I don't know how to have the same function if I have multiple datepickers in the same page. I can't classify them in a class cause then they aren't able to validate according to the correct start and end datepickers.

I've searched everywhere but still unable to find a solution. Hope someone can help me with this! 
Thank you

This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start1").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#end1").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
    }
});
    $("#end1").datepicker({ 
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
       $("#start1").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
    }
});  
});
```

This is my html for 1 datepicker each:

```
<input type="text" name="start1" placeholder="Start Date" id="start1" class="form-control" />'
<input type="text" name="end1"  placeholder="End Date" id="end1" class="form-control" />
```

If there are more than 1 datepicker the code is as such:

```
<input type="text" name="start" placeholder="Start Date" id="start<%=i%>" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="end"  placeholder="End Date" id="end<%=i%>" class="form-control" />
```

where i represents a number depending on the size of an array

Comment: Just to clarify, you want two datepickers, one for the start date and one for the end date? And if the start date datepicker is set, you want to ensure end date can't be before the start date? Or something else?

Comment: not clear if issue is how to initialize datepickers or how to set up form validation.Please provide code you are having problems with

Comment: Hi both, I accidentally submitted by pressing enter. Have updated my question!

Comment: @Sheryl-AnnLee is the size of array (i) dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I just used a class start and class end and called the datepicker function using those. for validation and manipulation, i left the ids the way they are and you can use those to validate/manipulate the fields.</strike>

**UPDATE:::**

After a few hours of my initial answer, I am now updating my answer to take into consideration of my understanding what OP wanted after a few communication between us through comments section. The code snippet and the fiddle links are also updated to the new answer.

Main thing I introduced is a new data attribute to the input tags "data-grp". So every start/end date pair gets to be part of a unique data-grp. In my code example, I have used 2 pairs of start/end date and with data attribure of data-grp="1" and data-grp="2". Now using that I have tweaked the datepicket call instantiation to uniquely identify the correct data groups and apply the min/max date feature/option to that particular group only.

Hope this is what you were looking for...

Jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/2k72adyL/6/

Code snippet as follows....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".datePickStart").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      var datagrp = $(this).attr('data-grp');
      var end_currdatagrp = ".end[data-grp='" + datagrp + "']";
      var start_currdatagrp = ".start[data-grp='" + datagrp + "']";
      $(end_currdatagrp).datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);

    }
  });

  $(".datePickEnd").datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      var datagrp = $(this).attr('data-grp');
      var start_currdatagrp = ".start[data-grp='" + datagrp + "']";
      $(start_currdatagrp).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
Start1:
<input type="text" name="start1" placeholder="Start Date" id="start1" class="form-control start datePickStart" data-grp="1" />
<br>
<br>End1:
<input type="text" name="end1" placeholder="End Date" id="end1" class="form-control end datePickEnd" data-grp="1" />
<hr>
<br>Start2:
<input type="text" name="start2" placeholder="Start Date" id="start2" class="form-control start datePickStart" data-grp="2" />
<br>
<br>End2:
<input type="text" name="end2" placeholder="End Date" id="end2" class="form-control end datePickEnd" data-grp="2" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. But it isnt working the way it should. because if i were to enter the dates in start 1 end 1 start 2 end 2, when i want to modify start 1 date it's max limit is end 2's date.

Comment: @Sheryl-AnnLee - So you want all the start and end pairs to be seperate?

Comment: @Sheryl-AnnLee- Can you please clarify me in plain english of what you were trying to do in the line...$(".start").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected). Just trying to understand the business logic. thanks

Comment: Yes all pairs are seperated. So start1 and end1 they validate against each other, start2 and end2 validates against each other and so on and so forth if I have more than 2 sets. Because I have to set periods for an event. An event can have more than 1 period (start and end date). hope this helps

Comment: @Sheryl-AnnLee - Sorry for the late response. If you are still looking for a solution to this , check out my latest fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/2k72adyL/3/ . I will add an update to my answer as well

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It really helped. There was a minor bug in your code though which I managed to solve. The issue was that once I input an end date, and I click to re-enter the end date, it would validate the min available against itself and not the start date. You may view it here if you wish @ [jsfiddle.net/2k72adyL/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/2k72adyL/5/)

Comment: @Sheryl-AnnLee - Sorry my mistake. I did not try to test it against  all the test scenarios. But thanks and good catch. Also since now that you are using classes "datePickstart" and "datePickEnd", you do not need seperate classes "start" and "end" anymore. so just swap them with your classes.Glad I could be of help

Comment: @Sheryl-AnnLee - another thing in the your fiddle, add a mindate:1 in the datePickEnd section. This is to prevent one being able to select past date when using end date first before usinf start date..http://jsfiddle.net/2k72adyL/6/